# How do i create a DB2 UNION query using variables from a list

Tags: sql, list, variables, db2, union

So i have a union query like:

```
select count(id)
from table 1
where membernumber = 'x'
and castnumber = 'y'
union
select count(id)
from table 1
where membernumber = 'x'
and castnumber = 'y'
union
```

etc...

There will be over 200 unions coming from a list 2x 200 table with values for x and y in each row. So each union query has to get the value of x and y from the corresponding row (not in any particular order).
How can i achieve that ?
Thanks

Comment: Strange query. Is it really useful to get 200 (or less, since you use `UNION`, which eliminates duplicate values) counts without values for `membernumber` and `castnumber` in each row? Where do you get the list of values from? From some table (provide an example of its structure and data then) or from some application object?

Comment: As written, this query makes no sense.  Each subquery is exactly the same.  `union` removes duplicates, so you can just run the subquery once.  I assume you intend something else, such as the `'x'` and `'y'` values being different on each row, but that is not clear from the question.

Comment: The x and y values are different for each repeating query in the unions. values are stored in an excel table, but can be put anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE 
SESSION.PARAMETERS
(
  MEMBERNUMBER INT
, CASTNUMBER INT
) DEFINITION ONLY WITH REPLACE
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;

-- Insert all the the constants in your application with
INSERT INTO SESSION.PARAMETERS 
(MEMBERNUMBER, CASTNUMBER)
VALUES (?, ?);

-- I don't know the meaning of the result you want to get 
-- but it's equivalent
select distinct count(t.id)
from table1 t
join session.parameters p
on p.membernumber = t.membernumber
and p.castnumber = t.castnumber
group by t.membernumber, t.castnumber;
```